# Javascript: Traversing through array and accessing its various elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split, traversal

Essentially what I'm trying to do right now is, given some input text, I split it up by white space and display on a

```
div id= "animation"
```

Every time a button is clicked, the array should go forward one word.

This is my current attempt.

```
function displayText() {
    var displayText = document.getElementbyID("animation");
    var list = (document.getElementbyID("input").split(/[ \tn]+/);
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        displayText.innerHTML = list.get[i];
    }
}
```

Is my thought process somewhat correct? For whatever reason, it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple issues in your method

```
function displayText() {
    var displayTextAnimation = document.getElementbyID("animation"); //keep variable name and method name different
    var list = (document.getElementbyID("input").value).split(/[ \tn]+/); //use value property and observe extra bracket
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        displayTextAnimation.innerHTML = list.charAt(i); //observe replacing get by charAt
    }
}
```

Comment: `displayTextAnimation.innerHTML = list.get[i];` What about this line? Looks completely wrong to me.

Comment: If you haven't noticed, `.charAt[i]` doesn't really make sense since `.charAt` is a function, and you are overwriting its inner HTML everytime.

Comment: is .charAt(i) really correct? I thought that .split creates an array of Strings, not characters

Comment: For some reason it still doesn't seem to display anything